# horizon not syncing

Tags: horizon

i have some problem with a test-net horizon that is not syncing.
I'm using the quickstart docker image and i see core is fully synced (state: "Synced!").

On horizon i see that history.latest_ledger and core_latest_ledger: 552182 are in sync and on the latest values corresponding to the pub-testnet.
On the log i see, that horizon is ingesting the newest ledgers.

But on horizon the history.elder_ledger is somehow on 180735.
Of course i can't see any new transactions in the horizon db.

Can someone explain please, what those 2 values mean? history.latest_ledger and history.elder_ledger.

Also, how can i get horizon to sync everything? I tried all different ways from https://www.stellar.org/developers/software/known-issues.html
but nothing helps.

Also tried CATCHUP_COMPLETE=true with no luck.

Comment: sorry i was wrong. New transaction are ingested correctly but horizon does not ingest the missing once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`history.latest_ledger` is the most recent ledger ingested by horizon from stellar core.

`history.elder_ledger` is the oldest ledger ingested by horizon from stellar core.

When horizon is ingesting new ledgers from stellar core, `history.latest_ledger` and `core_latest_ledger` are usually equal, or differ by a value of 1.

To have horizon ingest the complete history, you need to add the following configurations

- `CATCHUP_COMPLETE=true` on stellar core (I believe you have done this)
- `HISTORY_RETENTION_COUNT=0` horizon

Note that you will need to stop the running horizon service, empty the horizon database and restart the service for this to take effect.